# What is wrong with my Apache configuration?

Tags: apache2

I have in my sites-available a 000-default.conf (its empty):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

 </VirtualHost>
```

and another .conf file which I have already enabled (in the sites-available directory). This:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
            # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
            # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
            # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
            # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
            # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
            # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
            ServerName asd.com
            ServerAlias www.asd.com

            ServerAdmin info@asd.com
            DocumentRoot /srv/rypock

            <Directory /srv/rypock/>
                    AllowOverride All
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn

            ErrorLog /srv/asd-log/error.log
            CustomLog /srv/asd-log/access.log combined

            # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
            # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
            # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
            # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
            # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
            #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit asd.com my site does not get served up. I have restarted the server already. What is the problem?

Comment: Need more info. First check DNS resolution and update your above to confirm it resolves. The easiest way is ping both `asd.com` and `www.asd.com`.  Also if you aren't using the default, recommend disabling it with `a2dissite`.  Last, copy and provide any information in `/srv/asd-log/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your site is enabled. You also need to make sure the `asd.com` is pointing to your site.

Enable your site and restart Apache with the following commands (Replace `another` with whatever the file is called):

```
sudo a2ensite another.conf
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

If this site is on your local machine, you can edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add the following line to it (Replace the IP if it the site is on a different machine):

```
127.0.1.1       asd.com
```

If this was a live site with real DNS entries, you may need to wait a while until the DNS entries have been propagated and updated in case you had updated it from an older value.

Note: As @Mark suggested in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947043/what-is-wrong-with-my-apache-configuration#comment1506126_947043), you can disable the default Virtual Host with `a2dissite`.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

Comment: thank u very much. it was a problem of not setting up A records on my hosting provider